# how to create object to array in js

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have got object . I want to convert object to array

```
const object1 = {
  a: { hide:true},
  b:{}
};
```

I am using Object.entries to convert array, but I really confused how it would be ?

```
Object.entries(object1)
```

Output:

```
[{a:{hide:true}},{b:{}}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the desired output you need to loop over the return value of Object.entries and build object for each element

```js
const object1 = {
  a: { hide:true},
  b:{}
};

let final = Object.entries(object1).map(v=> Object.fromEntries([v]))

console.log(final)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could map the entries with their generated objects.

```js
const
    object = { a: { hide: true }, b:{} },
    result = Object
        .entries(object)
        .map(pair => Object.fromEntries([pair]));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because the properties of your object are objects again.

Both properties a and b are objects through the curly brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Use `map` on `Object.entries` and destructuring and return the object in map function.

```js
const obj = {
  a: { hide:true},
  b:{}
};

const output = Object.entries(obj).map(([key, value]) => ({[key]: value}))

console.log(output)
```